# Unable to do database testing through qtp

Tags: qtp, database-testing

i been given a task to do dabase testing on QTP for a website on number of user signing up and checking if the username is not dublicate of the one stored before.I am stuck on the very 1st step to establish connection as am new to QTP.Client given me database acess through godaddy account. www.godaddy.com.

How should i connect the SQL Server on that?To be precise what path i should give?
Do I need to have QL server installed in my laptop to check that or since i been given acess to their server directly though this site i can go further?

Con.Open "Provider_***_*___**;Server=**__**,Uid=**___***pwd=*_"

Comment: Totally unclear what exactly is the problem. What does godaddy.com have to do with this? What have you tried? Check out the FAQs, please.

Comment: What are your options for data connection in QTP?  First, please research and that should provide a framework for making a decision.  Concentrate on finding either a native SQL Server connection versus an ODBC option.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Refer www.connectionstrings.com and setup your correct connection string. Then use ADODB.Connection object to connect to your database in QTP.